# Trouble adding color bar to Hive Plot in R

Tags: r, plot, data-visualization

I'm working with a hive plot and want to know how to get a vertical color bar placed in the upper left quadrant of the plot, (not one that is off to the side of the plot). Problem is, whenever I run this code I'm not seeing anything pop up.  I believe that could be because the methods I've been trying are all for normal plots, not hive plots.

```
colorplot.l <- seq(1,100,1)
require("grid")
require("HiveR")
test2 <- ranHiveData(nx = 2)
plotHive(test2, ch = 5, axLabs = c("axis 1", "axis 2"), rot = c(-90, 90),
axLab.pos = c(20, 20), axLab.gpar = gpar(col = "pink", fontsize = 14, lwd = 2),
arrow = c("radius units", 0, 20, 60, 25, 40))
colorbar.plot(0,100,colorplot.l, horizontal=FALSE)
```

Am I doing something wrong or is there another way specifically for a hive plot?   Most packages I find don't work with this.

Any help or insight is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a viewport with the `grid` package you can add a color bar to your hive plot:

```
library(grid)

# A viewport on the upper left corner of the plot
legendViewport <- viewport(x=0.05, y=0.85, height=0.2, width=0.05)
pushViewport(legendViewport)

mypalette <- colorRampPalette(c("red","blue","green"))

# Render the color bar
grid.raster(mypalette(20), 
   width=unit(1,"npc"), height=unit(1,"npc"), int=FALSE)
```

Hope it can help you.

[image]